# How do i stop this jquery method from firing on onload?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this jquery function that is supposed to fire off when i call it.  Now it DOES fire off when I call it; however, and unfortunately, it also fires off at OnLoad.  How can I stop this from happening?

here is how I call the method:

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListType" CssClass="RadListBoxWZMenu" runat="server" OnClientDropped="LocationItem('Type')">
```

here is the method:

```
$(function LocationItem(zonetype) {
   var NewDialog = $('<div class="droppable"></div>');
   NewDialog.dialog({
   modal: false,
   title: $('<label>' + zonetype + '</label>'),
      show: 'clip',
      hide: 'clip',
      buttons: [
        { text: "Edit", click: function () { EditFields() } },
      ]
   });
   return false;

});
```

Comment: It's no use to name your function when wrapping it inside $();

`$(function LocationItem(zonetype) {});` is the same as `$(function(zonetype) {});`

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/McveF/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think wrapping it in the $() function means it is called when JQuery loads

Try removing the $() entirely

Answer (score 3):

Remove the encapsulating parenthesis, leading dollar sign and trailing semi-colon (i.e. `$();`).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap the function in the `$`. If you just put the function like this in your code:

```
function LocationItem(zonetype) {
   var NewDialog = $('<div class="droppable"></div>');
   NewDialog.dialog({
   modal: false,
   title: $('<label>' + zonetype + '</label>'),
      show: 'clip',
      hide: 'clip',
      buttons: [
        { text: "Edit", click: function () { EditFields() } },
      ]
   });
   return false;
}
```

Then you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping code in

```
$( //your code )
```

is equivalent to

```
$(document).ready( //your code )
```